# D3.js: transform text group based on width of longest string

Tags: d3.js

I'm appending a text group to a graph and would like to move all text elements down by the width of the longest string.

Here's my code:

```
chart.append('g')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style("text-anchor","start")
    .text(function(d){return d.top;})
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate (" + x(d.year) + ",
      " + (this.getComputedTextLength()) + ") " + "rotate(-90)"
    });
```

Which gives me:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qLQf.png)

The problem is `this.getComputedTextLength()` gets the length of each string individually. What I'd like is to move ALL the strings down by the width of the longest string:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Tj9.png)

The reason I can't do a simple transform by a fixed length is that I have an update function to change my data source. In other words, the lengths of the text strings are not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd translate the `g` wrapping the text:

```
var maxLen = 0;
var g = chart.append('g');
g.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .style("text-anchor","start")
  .text(function(d){return d;})
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var len = this.getComputedTextLength();
    if (len > maxLen) maxLen = len;
    return "translate (" + (i * 20) + ",0)rotate(-90)";
  });
g.attr("transform", "translate(10, "+ maxLen +")");
```

---

Full code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var data = "two roads diverge in yellow wooddddddddddddd and I took".split(" ");
      
      var chart = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);
      
      var maxLen = 0;
      var g = chart.append('g');
      g.selectAll('text')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("text-anchor","start")
        .text(function(d){return d;})
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          var len = this.getComputedTextLength();
          if (len > maxLen) maxLen = len;
          return "translate (" + (i * 20) + ",0)rotate(-90)";
        });
      g.attr("transform", "translate(10, "+ maxLen +")");
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```